# Two different queries - Returning inconsistent results

Tags: c#, linq, nosql, ravendb

I am getting two different results while I would expect the result to be same no matter how I query the database. In the result of query 1, I am getting a list of value pairs like

NY 3

AL 6

WI 5

etc..

But when I run query 2 to test if my values are accurate or not.. and when I specifically run and get by state "NY", I am getting a totally different number for NY. They are just not matching for any state. I am not sure any more as to which one is the accurate number.

Query 1:

```
//Edit
int countTheaters =  session.Query<Theaters>()
                        .Count();

var TheaterByStateList = session.Query<Theaters>()
                        .Take(countTheaters)
                        .ToList()
                        .GroupBy(x => x.State)
                        .OrderBy(x =>x.Count())
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

Query 2:

```
int TheaterCountByState = session.Query<Theaters>()
                            .Where(x => x.State== "NY")
                            .Count();
```

Comment: And if you just query the database through a management tool?

Comment: ZVenue, what do you really expect from RavenDB? You've asked a couple of questions here and poeple gave you good answers, but it seems that you are strictly ignoring all them and also all best-practise examples that are easily available on ravens website, blogs, sample-apps, etc. This has nothing to do with your strange naming-conventions (plural for class-names or capitalized variables) but if you would have used an index for grouping (see your last question), this wouldn't be an issue. Btw. it's the wrong usage of .Take() here that causes your issues. Sorry for being that honest.

Comment: As for the .Take() thing -> it has a limit, so even if you specify something as large as 5000, it will only return the number of items defined in the sever-config.

Comment: what you say is True.. I am implementing the map reduce index simulataneously. Thats what I will do finally in the actual application. I am just trying to learn few things here.. and thanks to you and others, already learned lot of new information. Saw the discrepancy and was curious to know why..

Comment: As for crazy naming conventions.. these are not real ones.. I am just making these up on the go.. while learning.. dont fear :-) I have naming conventions that you will approve readily.. sorry if that bugged you.. next time I will keep this in mind while posting.

Comment: @Daniel Lang can you post your comment as an answer.. I will mark it as answer. Thank you

Comment: Ok, I done that. Hope it helps, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is, that .Take() only returns the maximum number of records that have been set in the RavenDB server configuration. This is because ravens safe-by-design philosophy that should make you fail early (in development) and thus help you avoid a lot of pain that could happen if you weren't aware of the means of not paging (something that people commonly run into with NHibernate or EF2).

So by default, without specifiying anything else, you only get 128 records. You can change that on the client, but you will never get more records at once than the number that has been set on the server (1024 I think, but shouldn't care anyway - there's no reason why somebody would want to change these limits).

Answer (score 2):

We don't know your schema, so it's hard to tell. But I am pretty sure your problem lies here:

```
 .Take(countTheaters)
```

This means you run your grouping on only the first `countTheaters` rows, while your other query example counts on all the rows in the database.

Comment: Sorry  I missed a line there. I updated my code... countTheaters is the total number of records.. so both queries should be up agains the same number..

Comment: countTheaters is set to the count of the enumerable so it should take all of them (and be redundant) unless the code is really obfuscated and the count changes between the two calls

Comment: The only other significant difference that is apparent from the code is that one version does group by in memory, while the other counts instances of "NY" on the database. That might cause a difference (collation settings / case sensitivity) ? Again, it's hard to tell without having access to the data.

Comment: @Rune FS I am seeing a big difference in numbers. I dont believe count is changing that fast.

Comment: @driis Yes thats true. One is group by in memory .. but collation and case sensitivity are not causes I can confirm.